# How to Identify Objects, their Methods and Properties?

Tags: oop, methods, properties

This question may seem open-ended but I am not sure where or how else to ask this.  When writing object-oriented code one must determine the objects, methods and properties associated with what they're writing.  **I have a hard time doing this** and so **I am wondering if there is software or some sort of template that is out there to help me out with this**.

For example if my object is a `Car` a few methods could be `.engineStart()`, `.closeDoor(doorNumber)` and a few properties could be `color`, `make`, `licensePlateNumber`.

Does anyone have a format or technique that they use to identify all the objects, methods, and properties **before** they actually start coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class should handle a single aspect of the system to be built in the context of the chosen design.

An interface should be minimal (no sugar and convenience functions). This means that if you can realize a use case with a subset of the interface a function which would realize that use case should not be a member function.

Example:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
    void TurnLeft(uint32_t radians);
    void TurnRight(uint32_t radians);
    // Bad - interface not minimal and this is a convenience function.
    void TurnLeftThenRight(uint32_t radiansLeft, uint32_t radiansRight); 
};
```

A class should be an abstraction of sorts. This means, that it should not require all implementation details of the class and the full understanding of all its requirements used to implement it when using the class. Using the class correctly should be easier than implementing it.

A class should not simply "export" all state it encapsulates by means of properties as then it would not be an abstraction but simply a group of data.

For a class to be of practical use, it will make assumptions about the context it finds itself in and the general architecture. (Threading, memory usage policies, stack usage (recursions yes/no), exceptions yes/no, ...). Trying to factor all that out of the class or turn it into a multiple template parameter monster usually is not an optimal strategy for application programming.

A class implementation should have a unit test and some form of documentation about it's constraints and assumptions taken.

Class methods should be implemented in a defensive style. I.e. before optimization and tuning phase, a class should check input arguments and if possible also its output arguments and state against its constraints.

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about the design of your program take into account:

The classes, methods and data needed.

Relationships among and between your classes.

How the information will be stored, etc.

So just try making a very detailed description of your program and what you want it to do.  Then run through your description and pick out certain nouns and verbs that could help you specify things such as objects, attributes, and methods.  From here you can then see how you would like to maybe organize your classes and data.  Try not to make one class too complex or too small either.

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but I hope I could help.

Comment: So would you say the nouns in my description could be the objects? Object = noun, Methods = verb ?

Comment: Sure. So maybe like singular nouns could be basic classes that represent objects.  In that class you can define its attributes.  Then any verbs that sound useful can be placed as methods within those classes appropriately.

Comment: One more thing, lets say I have a `Lamp` class.  A lamp obviously has a light bulb.  If one was to create a separate class for the light bulb would it make more sense to inherit from the lamp class EX: (`class LightBulb inherits from Lamp`) or to create a separate class all together for `Bulb` without inheritance?

Answer (score -1):

Well when you start coding you need to determine what needs to be associated with what.  Meaning, I know I have a car with all of these properties.  So I need a car class with the following properties: color, make, plate number, gas mileage.  Now I want to know how much this car is average.  I can make a function in the car class specifically for the object that can be called to generate a price based off of parameters I input OR by the properties of the object itself.

This might not help or make sense but as you code you will see when and where to use classes.

Comment: I would like to identify all my objects before I start coding and not during.

Comment: Defining before and during create the same results.  You just have to decide what your object represents and what its properties need to define.  Planning is great but you will always find yourself add and removing functionality as you go.  So you are asking a broad and highly individualistic question.

Comment: I don't disagree with you that the functionality will change as I code.  However, we can limit the amount of change, errors and improve overall code quality if we define everything that we can before hand.  _You are much more likely to get away with robbing a bank if you plan your heist than if you where to improvise as you go._